# How to avoid Airflow to backfill when using trigger_dag?

Tags: airflow

I want to create a DAG that will only run upon an external trigger (i.e., using the 'airflow trigger_dag ' command). However, when I do this, I see multiple 'scheduled_xxx' DagRuns in addition to the 'manual_xxx' that I want. I am assuming the scheduled_xxx DagRuns are created to backfill?

Is there a way to only have the 'manual_xxx' DagRun created and no 'scheduled_xxx' DagRuns?

I tried different values for start_date (past, datetime.now() and future but got the same result. Here's my toy DAG ...

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = {
 'start_date': datetime.now(),   (also tried past and future dates)
 'schedule_interval': None,
 'depends_on_past': False,
}

dag = DAG('my_test_dag', default_args=default_args)

date_task = BashOperator(
 task_id='date',
 bash_command='date',
 dag=dag)
```

This is how I am issuing the trigger_dag command ...

```
airflow trigger_dag my_test_dag
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the "schedule_interval" is not a task level parameter. If I move it to the DAG object then I get the expected result. That is, I only get the manually triggered DagRun when I add the 'schedule_interval' argument to the DAG constructor ..

```
default_args = {
 'start_date': datetime.now(),   (also tried past and future dates)
 'depends_on_past': False,
}
dag = DAG('my_test_dag', default_args=default_args, **schedule_interval=None**)
```

This results in only a single DagRun getting created for each external/manual trigger (trigger_dag).